# DownloadManager Error Message when opening the file

Tags: android, download, download-manager

hey guys im making this simple app to fetch apk's that are stored on a server for clients.
i get the file downloaded and i want to open it to install.

so the first issue is that it downloads it twice?
second is i get error parsing application when it opens it?but if i open the file from the phone it works..

First downloading from my adapter :

```
 Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                        .mkdirs();

                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService (Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);


                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request (Uri.parse (appUrlString));
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes (DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);

                request.setDescription ("Downloading");
                request.setTitle (appName);

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner ();
                request.setNotificationVisibility (
                        DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);


                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,  appName+".apk");

                manager.enqueue (request);
                mCallback.onClick (String.valueOf (manager.enqueue (request)),appName);

            }
        });
```

Opening the file from my Main Activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver () {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Fetching the download id received with the broadcast
            long id = intent.getLongExtra (DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

            spinner.setVisibility (View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText (context, "Download Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

            Log.d ("INTENT ", String.valueOf (id) + "DID " + downloadID);
            openDownloadedAttachment(context, id);          
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(String value, String fileName) {
        spinner.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d ("INTENT REC", value + " " + fileName);
        fileNameDownloaded = fileName;
        downloadID = value;
    }

private void openDownloadedAttachment(final Context context, final long downloadId) {
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService (Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query ();
        query.setFilterById (downloadId);
        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query (query);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst ()) {
            int downloadStatus = cursor.getInt (cursor.getColumnIndex (DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
            String downloadLocalUri = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
            String downloadMimeType = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE));
            if ((downloadStatus == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) && downloadLocalUri != null) {
                openDownloadedAttachment (context, Uri.parse (downloadLocalUri), downloadMimeType);
            }
        }
        cursor.close ();
    }

    private void openDownloadedAttachment(final Context context, Uri attachmentUri, final String attachmentMimeType) {
        if (attachmentUri != null) {
            // Get Content Uri.
            if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equals (attachmentUri.getScheme ())) {
                // FileUri - Convert it to contentUri.
                File file = new File (attachmentUri.getPath ());
                attachmentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile (MainActivity.this, "com.handshake.downloadmanager.provider", file);

                System.out.println ("Opening: " + attachmentUri);
            }

            Intent openAttachmentIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            openAttachmentIntent.setDataAndType (attachmentUri, attachmentMimeType);
            openAttachmentIntent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            try {
                context.startActivity (openAttachmentIntent);
                System.out.println ("Opening attachement: " + openAttachmentIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText (context, context.getString (R.string.unable_to_open_file), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have an interface that tells my mainActivity what is the id of the download and when it is done.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

```
provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provide_paths" />
        </provider>
```

So why does it download 2 times? and the error message when trying to open it?

EDIT:
i settle one issue with the error message for package error. need to open the app setting to all the app to install

```
 private void askSettings(){
        Intent intent = new Intent ();
        intent.setAction (Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts ("package", this.getPackageName (), null);
        intent.setData (uri);
        this.startActivity (intent);
    }
```

but the downloading 2 times is my headache lol

Comment: opening it may give the error as you have set the mime type wrong. The system manages to open it as it doesn't use your mime type but looks elsewhere

Comment: opening part is good now...its the downloading twice my issue now..

Comment: Your using a Spinner to select what to download? A spinner listener/callback usually calls back twice, once when you first set it and once when a selection is made. That might make for two downloads.

Comment: So i removed my spinner from the on create to the get Data.so i only call the spinner when i load the first time and when i click the app to download..still the same..very odd..

Answer (score 0):

So stupid mistake..lol

i send the request id to my interface but the way i sent it

```
mCallback.onClick (String.valueOf (manager.enqueue (request)),appName);
```

im calling the enqueue again..lol just needed to put request..uhh thx guys